# Rails 4 NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem and I don't realu understand it.
I have this error :

undefined method `value' for "test":String

here my view :

```
<div id="search">
    <%= form_for :search, url: search_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :value, :class => 'form-control input-sm', :placeholder => 'Search...' %>
    <%= button_tag '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>'.html_safe, :id => 'search-btn', :class => 'btn' %>
    <% end %>   
</div>
```

and here my controller :

```
def index
    @clubs = Club.all
    @search = params[:search][:value]
end
```

I think that the problem is about how I catch my variable :value but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick thought is that text_field has a :value parameter to set the default value.

Try changing :value to something else

```
<%= form_for :search, url: {} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :keywords, :value => params[:keywords], :class => 'form-control input-sm',      :placeholder => 'Search...' %>
  <%= button_tag '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>'.html_safe, :id => 'search-btn', :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Then

```
@search = params[:search][:keywords]
```